# 'mysql_warning_count' incorrectly returns 0 warnings after upgrade from MySQL 5.6 to MariaDB 10.3

Tags: c, mysql-connector, mariadb-connector-c

I am using "MySQL Connector for C v6.1.11" to connect to a MySQL 5.6.35 server.

When I use `mysql_real_query()` to run a query like `SELECT MAKETIME(-1000,57,33)`, `mysql_warning_count()` correctly returns 1 warning (`SHOW WARNINGS` will say "Truncated incorrect time value: -1000:57:33").

I've recently drop-in replaced the MySQL 5.6.35 server with MariaDB 10.3.13. The same query's `mysql_warning_count()` **now returns 0 warnings**. However, `SHOW WARNINGS` will **still list the warning** (as expected).

I tried replacing my old MySQL Connector library with the latest MariaDB Connector/C (v3.1.6), but the problem persists.

**What would cause query warnings to not be reported? Do I need to set a flag somewhere, or apply some compatibility settings?**

SQL mode used is the default, namely:
For MySQL 5.6:  `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
For MariaDB 10.3: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO , NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

The only client flags passed to `mysql_real_connect()` are `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS | CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS` (both for MySQL and MariaDB)